# save char in a specific position and line in a text file (bash)

Tags: bash

This is the content of the file that my bash script is trying to read and use:

```
AAAA
0  1  2
BBBB
```

How could I save the character "0" (which is in the position 1 of the line 2) in a variable that I can use inside my bash script? Take into consideration that this char (0) is not unique so I cannot used it as a search pattern by itself

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options to extract the character:

```
sed -n '2s/\(.\).*/\1/p' file
```

or

```
awk -F '' 'NR==2 {print $1}' file
```

You can redirect the output to a new file `> newfile` or save the result as a variable using command substitution `var=$(...)`

---

If you really want to do it "in bash", then

```
n=0
while read line; do 
  ((++n == 2)) && { echo "${line:0:1}"; break; }
done < file
```